# Return value from method

Tags: c#

I am creating calculator with 20 textboxes - 10 for input, 10 for output. After creating a method into which I put parameter(defined in the first 10 textboxes) I return value to main method.

To get all 10 values is it really necessary to write code for all 10 or more text boxes as I have already started or there is smarter way how to pass into the method textbox parameters and return multiple values at once?

UPDATE:

As you recomended I created List of Tuples and used foreach loop to loop through them, but now i get error:
Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'. Could you help me to point out where the problem is?

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
    {

        List<Tuple<TextBox,TextBox>> tuple1 = new List<Tuple<TextBox,TextBox>>();
        tuple1.Add(Tuple.Create(textBox1, textBox2));
        tuple1.Add(Tuple.Create(textBox3, textBox4));
        tuple1.Add(Tuple.Create(textBox5, textBox6));
        tuple1.Add(Tuple.Create(textBox7, textBox8));


        foreach (Tuple<TextBox,TextBox> box in tuple1)
        {
            var inputBox = box.Item1;
            var outputBox = box.Item2;
            outputBox.Text = MethodA(Convert.ToInt32(inputBox.Text));
        }
    }

    private int MethodA(int Parameter1)
    {
    int A = Parameter1;
    int B = 20;
    int C;

    if (A == 16 && B == 20) { C = 15; } else if (A == 20 && B == 20) { C = 25; } else { C = 0; };
    return C;
    }
```

Comment: 1) Create a dictionary or list of tuples to link the textbox pairs, 2) loop through the collection getting the input from one textbox and putting the output in the other.  Returning multiple values from a method is not good practice (and not necessary here).

Comment: Are you using Window Forms?

Comment: Yes, I am using Window Forms. I guess this Tuple class is a bit too complex for a newbie like me, so I will google around to see what it actualy is and what it does and then get back to this post. Thank you for help.

Comment: @D Stanley, @Michael Any ideas, guys?

Answer (score 0):

You could store all the input-output textbox combination in the constructor:

```
private List<Tuple<TextBox, TextBox>> textBoxes = new List<Tuple<TextBox, TextBox>>();

public Form1() {
    InitializeComponents();
    textBoxes.add(Tuple.Create(textBox1, textBox4);
    // ...
}
```

And then, in `button1_Click`, just iterate over all the textboxes:

```
foreach (Tuple<TextBox, TextBox> boxes in textBoxes) {
    var inputBox = boxes.Item1;
    var outputBox = boxes.Item2;
    outputBox.Text = MethodA(Convert.ToInt32(inputBox.Text));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best answer, but it would work:

```
public class Extensions
{
     public MethodA(this TextBox tb)
     {
         tb.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(tb.Text) + 5).ToString();
     }
}
```

now you can just call:

```
 textBox1.MethodA();
 textBox2.MethodA();
```

...etc.

This isn't necessarily recommended, but it's one way you could simply doing this multiple times.

If you won't be repeating this, it'd probably be better to just inline the logic the same way:

```
 textBox1.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) + 5).ToString();
 textBox2.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text) + 5).ToString();
 textBox3.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text) + 5).ToString();
```